# Why does this SQL work on one version of MySql-Server but not another?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, datetime

I'm trying to run the following very simple SQL command on two different MySQL databases:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    created DATETIME(6) NOT NULL, 
    updated DATETIME(6) NOT NULL, 
    my_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (my_id), 
    UNIQUE (name)
);
```

This mysql fails when I run it against `mysql-server 5.5`. 
But it succeeds when I run it against `mysql-server 5.6`. Why?

Below you can see how actually ran it. Apparently 5.5 doesn't allow giving an integer-size with a DATETIME column.

***Failing Case:***

```
    # mysql -D my_db_instance -h 127.0.0.1
    Reading table information for completion of table and column names
    You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 938
    Server version: 5.5.46 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

    Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.

    Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

    mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable (
        ->     created DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
        ->     updated DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
        ->     my_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ->     name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ->     PRIMARY KEY (my_id),
        ->     UNIQUE (name)
        -> );

    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
        updated DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
        my_id INTEGER NOT NULL A' at line 2
```

***Succeeding Case:***

```
    $ mysql -u myuser -p -D my_db_instance -h 127.0.0.1
    Enter password:
    Reading table information for completion of table and column names
    You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 6
    Server version: 5.6.21 Homebrew

    Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.

    Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

    mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable (
        ->     created DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
        ->     updated DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
        ->     my_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ->     name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ->     PRIMARY KEY (my_id),
        ->     UNIQUE (name)
        -> );
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Just check the online documentation. The syntax (and the new types) were added in version 5.6

Comment: I checked the release notes for mysql-5.6. Nowhere do I see any mention of a change in the datetime format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype `DATETIME` used to be only `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.  But, beginning with 5.6.4(?), [fractional seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) were allowed.  `DATETIME(6)` allows for microseconds:  `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff`.

If you want that `CREATE` to work on both versions, remove the `(6)`.  Notice how the error message pointed exactly at that.